# 2D inferential mapping

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spatial, epidemiology

I have a dataset that maps vein positions in the calf. This is a dataset of 14,000 (x, y) positional coordinates (one set of (x, y) per vein), using common anatomical landmarks. I have plotted these data on a heat map and it appears that these veins tend to cluster in particular areas.

I would like to ask, what statistical test you would recommend to show that these clusters are statistically different from the background rate? 
As I understand it, this situation should be similar to crime/disease area mapping showing a statistically significant difference between incidences on a 2D map. I haven't found any useful resources online to go through these procedures.

Comment: Are you, or would anybody, really be in any doubt about the clustering?  If not, then running a test would seem pointless.

Comment: Hi Whuber, Thanks for your reply. The clustering is quite distinct. But coming from a medical background I know that surgeons will want to see a low p-value before they will accept anything. There are also some previously undescribed clusters which are less common than the historically  accepted clusters of veins. If there is a way to show that the incidence of these new, less common clusters is higher than would be expected by chance alone then I'll have a great paper. I just need to know that names of possible tests so I can go away and look them up. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: You would likely have a stronger paper if you were to focus on the meaning and quantification of your observations.  An appropriate graphic ought to make your case in an impressive fashion. Perhaps, to mollify editors who do not understand statistics, you could make the point that statistics (particularly p-values) are not intended for sanctifying a conclusion, especially when it is an obvious one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Whuber, I think you make a good point about the focus of the paper. Not to get too bogged down in statistics that are proving the obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what it is you want to test when you want to *show that these clusters are statistically different from the background rate*. Is there a background rate of clusters? Or just a background rate of vein locations and you want to show that your pattern of veins is "more clustered" than expected from a completely random (in 2D space) pattern of veins? A very common tool is Ripley's K-function, which may be well-know in your field. I have co-authored a book where this is explained from scratch; see http://book.spatstat.org/ where Chapter 7 is relevant and free to download. It is especially useful if you are willing to use R and the package `spatstat` for your analysis.

Comment: Hi Ege, Yes I want to show that the veins are "more clustered" than completely random. Many thanks for the download to your book, I will read that and hopefully understand it. Luckily I was using R already so it sounds perfect.

Comment: Remember that if the intensity of veins is non-constant across your observation region (e.g. in general there are more points in one side of the region than in the other) you need to take this into account. Otherwise, the null model is called complete spatial randomness (CSR) and there are many tests with CSR as the null hypothesis. Good luck! (Also if this answer is sufficient for your needs, consider marking it as an accepted answer so it doesn't show up as unanswered in searches.)

Comment: Hi Ege, thank you very much for your generous download. One problem I have run into is that spatstat doesn't like duplicate data points. Since my data set is large I have lots of duplicate coordinate points which spatstat removes before performing any analysis. Surely they should stay in the analysis? If so, what can be done to identify and count these clusters?

Comment: If duplication is due to discretisation one strategy is to randomly jitter the points and continue the analysis with these unique points. Then you should repeat the jittering and analysis several times to ensure the results are stable. If e.g the discretisation is on an integer lattice you can jitter the points in the box around the lattice point (i,j): [i-0.5,i+0.5]x[j-0.5,j+0.5].

Comment: Thanks Ege, I did wonder whether that would be a valid approach, but I didn't think of repeating it to check the stability of the results.